# How to fix the regex pattern for splitting string

Tags: regex, scala

I need to separate comparison operators (==, !=, >, <, >=, <=) from the string value.

I can have following possible combinations

```
== 1
== 100.24
== 120/numberOfRows
<= 1/3
>= 2232
```

I tried below regex pattern but it not working as expected.

```
    Pattern = "(<[=>]?|==|=<|=>|>=?|\\&\\&|\\|\\|) (\\w*\\.?\\w+\\.?\\/?\\w+)".r
```

Comment: Why not just `"""(<[=>]?|=[<>=]|>=?|!=|&&|\|\|)\s+(.+)""".r`?

Comment: Please show sample input and expected output

Comment: What's the story here? Who are you writing to and why use the deleted answer (below) as your channel of communication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```scala
"""(<[=>]?|=[<>=]|>=?|!=|&&|\|\|)\s+(.+)""".r
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RsGi7l/1). Details:

- `(<[=>]?|=[<>=]|>=?|!=|&&|\|\|)` - `<`, `<=`, `<>`, `=<`, `=<`, `=>`, `==`, `>`, `>=`, `!=`, `&&` or `||`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(.+)` - Group 2: any one or more chars, other than line break chars, as many as possible.